# arm assembler: bx jump to nowhere

Tags: c, function, assembly, microcontroller

I try to write some assembler code inside C, and then call C function. My code is as follows:
C:

```
void my_fun(uint32_t *arg) {
   //sth
}
```

Assembler:

```
ldr r2, my_fun_label
bx r2
my_fun_label: .word my_fun
```

Using debuger I found r2 register contains some random value instead my_fun addres. So program branch to nowhere, and stays freezes. Can someone help me?
I'm using nRF52 ARM Cortex M4 microcontroller.

Edit:
The results

```
0003ea0a: my_fun: 

asm_test: 
0003ea26: ldr r2, [pc, #0] ;(0x3ea28 <asm_test+2>) 
0003ea28: bx r2 
0003ea2a: and.w r0, sp, r3
```

but `my_fun_label` seems points to `0x0dea0300`

Comment: How did you link this?  And BTW, you can use `ldr r2, =my_fun` and let the assembler make a literal pool for you if you don't need to take control of where it puts it.

Comment: If you lose your origin, how are you ever going home?

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not linking this. I'm using this in C code: `__asm volatile(";asm code")` It's not my idea, it's part of error handling function which i want modify.

Comment: If you compile but don't link, you'll have a `.o` or `.obj` that you can't run.  Anyway, edit your question with your exact code, because apparently this is *not* it.  You didn't even mention using inline asm in the question!!  Also with how you build a binary from your source to make this a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

soc.c

```
void my_fun ( void )
{

}
```

sos.s

```
.thumb

ldr r2, my_fun_label
bx r2
my_fun_label: .word my_fun
```

build and disassemble

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mthumb -O2 -c soc.c -o soc.o
arm-none-eabi-as sos.s -o sos.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x1000 sos.o soc.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf

Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <my_fun_label-0x4>:
    1000:   4a00        ldr r2, [pc, #0]    ; (1004 <my_fun_label>)
    1002:   4710        bx  r2

00001004 <my_fun_label>:
    1004:   00001009    andeq   r1, r0, r9

00001008 <my_fun>:
    1008:   4770        bx  lr
    100a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
```

worked perfectly

might want to align the address so you are not gambling on a 50/50 chance of it working.

```
.thumb

ldr r2, my_fun_label
bx r2
nop
my_fun_label: .word my_fun
```

thank you gnu

```
arm-none-eabi-as sos.s -o sos.o
sos.s: Assembler messages:
sos.s:5: Error: invalid offset, target not word aligned (0x00000002)
sos.s:5: Error: invalid offset, value too big (0x00000002)
```

force alignment

```
.thumb

ldr r2, my_fun_label
bx r2
nop
.align
my_fun_label: .word my_fun
```

that is better

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <my_fun_label-0x8>:
    1000:   4a01        ldr r2, [pc, #4]    ; (1008 <my_fun_label>)
    1002:   4710        bx  r2
    1004:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
    1006:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

00001008 <my_fun_label>:
    1008:   0000100d    andeq   r1, r0, sp

0000100c <my_fun>:
    100c:   4770        bx  lr
    100e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
```

self modifying code is another story you might have to use barriers and/or deal with caching, etc...

Comment: and you cant execute assembly language, needs to be machine code.